# How to pass the array initialization as argument in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I expected that I can pass the array initialization as the attribute value in Blazor.

> Bazor that we are using an expression by prepending an @ symbol before
> the value we assign. Blazor will then try to interpret the text after
> the @ as a valid piece of C# code, such as a member name, or a method
> invocation.
>
> [Blazor
> University](https://blazor-university.com/components/literals-expressions-and-directives/)

```xml
<TasksGroupsTreeManager AdditionalCSS_Classes=@({ "TasksListPage-TasksManager" }) />
```

I got the error:

```
; exptected
```

It is possible to do what I want without the creating of new field/property?

### Full listing of Blazor component

```xml
@page "/"

<div class="TasksListPage-SpecificContent MainLayout-DynamicContentFillingChildrenElement">
  
  <TasksGroupsTreeManager AdditionalCSS_Classes=@({ "TasksListPage-TasksManager" }) /> 
  
  <div class="TasksListPage-TasksManager"></div>
  
  <div class="TasksListPage-TaskEditor"></div>
  
</div>
```

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: I don't think that error is from the provided line.

Comment: @viveknuna Thank you for the comment. I have added some screenshots. The error is on line 5.

Comment: @ddastrodd Thank you for the comment. Please take a look the appended screenshots.

Comment: There still isn't enough code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am sorry. I added the full listing of target Blazor component.

Comment: OK, I see what you're trying to do.  Array initialization is a compile-time feature; you can't pass your initialization data this way.  You'll have to pass it as an actual array instance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thank you for the comment. It means, "I should pass the reference to arrray-type field/property" like `AdditionalCSS_Classes=@AdditionalCSS_ClassesOfTasksGroupsTreeManager`? If so, it's better to make the `AdditionalCSS_Classes" the comma or space separated classes string ...

Comment: Probably. I wouldn't know for sure without being in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize array

<TasksGroupsTreeManager AdditionalCSS_Classes=@(new string[]{ "TasksListPage-TasksManager" }) />

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#component-parameters